# For loop in promise.then()?

Tags: node.js, ecmascript-6, es6-promise

I need to iterate between two values and create/touch files (I/O) on each iteration.

I'm using the [fs-promise](https://github.com/kevinbeaty/fs-promise) module to do so asynchronously:

```
const path = require('path');
const fsp = require('fs-promise');


function addPages(startAt, pages, mode) {
    let htmlExt = mode.HTML;
    let cssExt = mode.CSS;

    fsp.readFile(path.join('.', 'templates', 'body.html'), { encoding: 'utf-8' })
        .then((content) => {
            // return Promise.all(() => {}).then().catch(); // Do this.

            for (let i = startAt, endAt = startAt + pages; i < endAt; i++) {
                console.log(i);

                fsp.writeFile(path.join('.', 'manuscript', `page-${i}`, `style.${cssExt}`), '')
                    .then(() => { console.log('Yay!') })
                    .catch(console.log.bind(console));

                // fsp.writeFile(path.join('.', 'manuscript', `page-${i}`, `style.${cssExt}`), '')
                //     .then((i, templateHTML) => {
                //         fsp.writeFile(path.join('.', 'manuscript', `page-${i}`, `body.${htmlExt}`), content);
                //     })
                //     .catch((err) => {
                //         console.log.bind(console);
                //     });

            }

        })
        .catch((err) => {
            if (err) return error('Couldn\'t create pages', err);
        });
```

Now I did [read](https://pouchdb.com/2015/05/18/we-have-a-problem-with-promises.html) that `Promises.all([Array of promises])` is the way to go for looping inside the `then()` scope, but the question is why/how?

I'm unable to wrap my head around why the `for-loop` doesn't execute before the context moves out of the promised then() scope, and then how should I get to the expected outcome.

Comment: The loop *does* execute before the callback ends, but it doesn't wait for the asynchronous work. Put the promises you're creating in the loop in an array, and `return Promise.all(…)` from the `then` callback.

Comment: @Bergi - Another case where something like the [requested `Promise.loop()`](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/issues/1053) would be useful.

Comment: @jfriend00: Except this is tagged ES6-promise, not Bluebird :-)

Comment: @Bergi - I'm just pointing out a use-case for additional promise features.  I didn't say Bluebird belongs in this specific answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const path = require('path');
const fsp = require('fs-promise');

function addPages(startAt, pages, mode) {
    let htmlExt = mode.HTML;
    let cssExt = mode.CSS;

    return fsp.readFile(path.join('.', 'templates', 'body.html'), { encoding: 'utf-8' })
        .then((content) => {
            var pendingWrites = [];

            for (let i = startAt, endAt = startAt + pages; i < endAt; i++) {
                let filename = path.join('.', 'manuscript', `page-${i}`, `style.${cssExt}`);
                let thisWrite = fsp.writeFile(filename, '');

                pendingWrites.push(thisWrite);
            }

            return Promise.all(pendingWrites);
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            // either fully recover from the error or rethrow
            console.log("Could not add pages: ", err);
            throw err;
        });
}
```

As elaborated in the comments, resist the temptation to introduce none-functional `.catch()` handlers into your promise chain.

Non-functional means in this case: It does not recover from the error *and* does not rethrow the error. A catch handler that does not throw marks an error as handled, i.e. it returns a resolved promise, not a rejected one. This makes proper error handling later in the promise chain impossible. It's bad practice and unhelpful.

If you want to log the error, log it and rethrow it. If you have fully recovered from the error and subsequent code is unimpeded, don't rethrow.

Comment: `.catch(log)` will "handle" a promise rejection and not propagate it up the chain.  This is usually an anti-pattern as the higher level calling code will have no idea there were any errors.

Comment: @jfriend00 That's right. I was using the OPs code; it would be more useful not to handle the error at this stage, or at least to handle it better than merely logging it.

Comment: @marvinganig - And I'm trying to make sure the OP knows that this pattern is bad and I was hoping you would fix the badness in your answer or at least not continue using it in your answer.

Comment: @jfriend00 Agreed. Better now?

Comment: It would be even better if you educated the OP on the badness and explained why you removed it.  They may well decide they liked it there and just put it back in without knowing of the badness.  Of course, maybe my comments serve that purpose now.

Comment: On Nolan Lawson's blogpost on promises (See item #3: https://pouchdb.com/2015/05/18/we-have-a-problem-with-promises.html) he has put a comment in `.catch(log)` pattern there: `.catch(console.log.bind(console)); // <-- this is badass`. Badass why or why  is it an anti-pattern, I'm curious now.

Comment: @marvindanig I've added a blurb of explanation. Compare this: `function pr() { return Promise.reject('fubar') }` and then `pr().catch( err => console.log("ERROR", err) ).then( result => console.log('SUCCESS', result) );`

Comment: @marvindanig if that's the outermost promise in your code, IMHO it's a good thing.  It's bad if it's hidden away in an inner promise chain.